# MySQL - Update column with MAX or GREATEST Value from fields in row (excluding NULL)

Tags: mysql, null, max

In MySQL in the table `mytable` I want to UPDATE column `max_value`

Example before the query the table looks like:

```
___________________________________________________
|| id || value1 || value2 || value3 || max_value ||
___________________________________________________
|| 1  ||    1   ||   2    ||   3    ||   NULL    ||
===================================================
|| 2  ||    99  ||   2    ||   3    ||   NULL    ||
===================================================
|| 3  ||    1   ||   66   ||   66   ||   NULL    ||
===================================================
|| 4  ||    1   ||   2    ||  NULL  ||   NULL    ||
===================================================
|| 5  ||  NULL  ||  NULL  ||  NULL  ||   NULL    ||
___________________________________________________
```

Ater the SQL statement `max_value` should have been updated with the highest value of `value1`, `value2` or `value3`. Like this:

```
___________________________________________________
|| id || value1 || value2 || value3 || max_value ||
___________________________________________________
|| 1  ||    1   ||   2    ||   3    ||     3     ||
===================================================
|| 2  ||    99  ||   2    ||   3    ||     99    ||
===================================================
|| 3  ||    1   ||   66   ||   66   ||     66    ||
===================================================
|| 4  ||    1   ||   2    ||  NULL  ||     2     ||
===================================================
|| 5  ||  NULL  ||  NULL  ||  NULL  ||   NULL    ||
___________________________________________________
```

Can anyone give me a MySQL query for this?

Comment: 1. Normalize your data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GREATEST` doesn't interact with `NULL` in the way you need, but an `UPDATE`/`JOIN` will do it without *too* much complexity;

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
JOIN (
  SELECT id,MAX(value) value FROM (  
    SELECT id,value1 value FROM Table1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT id,value2       FROM Table1 UNION ALL
    SELECT id,value3       FROM Table1
  ) g GROUP BY id
) a ON t1.id = a.id
SET t1.max_value=a.value;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea273/1).

Comment: that even better since giving excactly what I requested. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

You have to replace `NULL` values with `0` or any value you like, else the comparision with an "unknown value" always returns an "unknown value".

```
update table1 
set max_value = greatest(coalesce(value1, 0), coalesce(value2, 0), coalesce(value3, 0));
```

The `coalesce()` function returns the first of its parameters which is `not null`

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1c7d/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable, (SELECT id,
    CASE
        WHEN value1>= value2 AND value1 >= value3 THEN value1
        WHEN value2 >= value1 AND value2 >= value3 THEN value2
        WHEN value3 >= value1 AND value3 >= value2 THEN value3        
    END AS value FROM mytable) ans 
  SET max_value = ans.value where ans.id=mytable.id ;
```

Comment: Will return exactly the same result as `GREATEST`, that is if one column is null, the result is null.